# mach-o but wrong architecture

Tags: architecture, mach-o, tix

I am trying to install a program called ARIA2.3 which is used to calculate protein structures using NMR data. This program requires another program called Tix to run the graphical interface. However, Tix proved to be a pain in the neck (to stay polite) to install. I think I managed to install it, but I still get an error when I launch ARIA's graphical interface with the command

```
aria --gui
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/Users/davidbernard/Desktop/RMN/aria2.3/aria2.py", line 875, in <module>
    run_gui(a['-g'])
  File "/Users/davidbernard/Desktop/RMN/aria2.3/aria2.py", line 556, in run_gui
    gui.go(project_file)
  File "/Users/davidbernard/Desktop/RMN/aria2.3/src/py/aria/gui/gui.py", line 1555, in go
    root = Tix.Tk()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tix.py", line 225, in __init__
    self.tk.eval('package require Tix')
_tkinter.TclError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/Tix8.4.3/libTix8.4.3.dylib, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/Tix8.4.3/libTix8.4.3.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I know that libTix8.4.3.dylib is in architecture x86_64. I am working on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and I don't know much about informatics. Can someone help me make ARIA work, please?